# Add watch window shows value but the value is not assigned to variable

Tags: c#, linq

The below code when checked in "Add watch" window shows the *right value* (`100`), but the value is not assigned to variable `_countVar`, the value is `0` which *is incorrect*.

Can someone tell me *what is wrong* in my code:

```
string _strVariable = "New York";

var _countVar = nestList
  .SelectMany((List<object> w) => w)
  .Count(w => w == _strVariable);
```

Comment: `List<object>` seems unlikely to ever *equal* `_strVariable` as it will be a *reference check*, what is in this `nestList`, and why would it *equal* `string` anyway... Lets take a step back, what is the definition of `nestList`, and what do you actually want to do

Comment: @MichaelRandall - nestedList is a list of list of objects, and am trying to compare if the child list has the string matching, I got only index in the list to find to compare with. Is it doable? Also why would "Add Watch" window shows value but not assigning?

Comment: @DeSon - Have you tried ToList() before Count() method?

Comment: @Smits - Yes, not working. Am not sure what is it am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if `w` is of type `object` in

```
...
.SelectMany((List<object> w) => w) // w is object
.Count(w => w == _strVariable);    // if w has the same reference as _strVariable
```

you actually compare *references*, not `string`s *values*. If `string`s *don't share* the same reference (they are not `Intern`ed), they will be considered *different*:

```
object x = "abc";

// some manipulations to prevent the compiler to intern x and y strings
string y = ("abc" + " ").Trim(); // "abc", note that y has the same value as x

Console.Write(x == y ? "equals" : $"{x} <> {y}");
```

Outcome:

```
abc <> abc
```

To compare `string`s *values* put `string.Equals`:

```
string _strVariable = "New York";

var _countVar = nestList
  .SelectMany(list => list)
  .Count(city => string.Equals(city, _strVariable));
```

Comment: string.equals worked fine. Can you tell me how is it that it displayed right value in add watch window? Just curious. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @DeSon: when you start *watch* window it *computes* the expression and may well *intern* the strings in the process. Actually, `w == _strVariable` is *unstable* it may depend on compiler, .net etc. if strings be interned or not